# Oracle SQL recursive adding values

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

I have the following data in the table

```
Period      Total_amount    R_total
01/01/20    2               2
01/02/20    5               null
01/03/20    3               null
01/04/20    8               null
01/05/20    31              null
```

Based on the above data I would like to have the following situation.

```
Period      Total_amount    R_total
01/01/20    2               2
01/02/20    5               3
01/03/20    3               0
01/04/20    8               8
01/05/20    31              23
```

Additional data

```
01/06/20    21              0 (previously it would be -2)
01/07/20    25              25
01/08/20    29              4
```

Pattern to the additional data is:
if total_amount < previous(r_total) then 0

Based on the filled data, we can spot the pattern is:
R_total = total_amount - previous(R_total)

Could you please help me out with this issue?

Comment: What is the real-life application of this? I am wondering if you modeled it correctly (in arithmetic - before ever thinking about how to *program* the solution). Alternate sums are interesting in pure math, but they very rarely appear naturally in real-life business applications.

Comment: Hi, it's like moving the excel calculation into the DB. Just of my curiosity is it possible to implement into your solution the mechanism, which transforms r_total minus values to 0 value, like in the example

Comment: "It's like moving the Excel calculation into the DB" - but what was the Excel calculation for? My question is about the real-life business problem that requires you to do that calculation in the first place - not **how** you do it (in the DB, in Excel, or even by hand on a piece of paper). What kind of business application needs that specific calculation?

Comment: If you need to replace each potential negative value with zero, and then use that zero in further computations, then it will be much easier to adapt the recursive CTE solution from Gordon's answer. The computation no longer has a clean, closed-form formula; it is really *recursive* in the deepest meaning of the term. It's a very different problem than the one you asked originally, even though they are so very closely related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Gordon Linoff suspected, it is possible to solve this problem with analytic functions. The benefit is that the query will likely be much faster. The price to pay for that benefit is that you need to do a bit of math beforehand (before ever thinking about "programming" and "computers").

A bit of elementary arithmetic shows that R_TOTAL is an alternating sum of TOTAL_AMOUNT. This can be arranged easily by using ROW_NUMBER() (to get the signs) and then an analytic SUM(), as shown below.

Table setup:

```
create table sample_data (period, total_amount) as
  select to_date('01/01/20', 'mm/dd/rr'),  2 from dual union all
  select to_date('01/02/20', 'mm/dd/rr'),  5 from dual union all
  select to_date('01/03/20', 'mm/dd/rr'),  3 from dual union all
  select to_date('01/04/20', 'mm/dd/rr'),  8 from dual union all
  select to_date('01/05/20', 'mm/dd/rr'), 31 from dual
;
```

Query and result:

```
with
  prep (period, total_amount, sgn) as ( 
    select period, total_amount, 
           case mod(row_number() over (order by period), 2) when 0 then 1 else -1 end
    from   sample_data
  )
select period, total_amount,
       sgn * sum(sgn * total_amount) over (order by period) as r_total
from   prep
;

PERIOD   TOTAL_AMOUNT    R_TOTAL
-------- ------------ ----------
01/01/20            2          2
01/02/20            5          3
01/03/20            3          0
01/04/20            8          8
01/05/20           31         23
```

Comment: @mno013: this is more efficient - and simpler - than the recursive query solution. You might want to consider accepting *this* answer.

Answer (score 2):

This may be possible with window functions, but the simplest method is probably a recursive CTE:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by period) as seqnum
      from yourtable t
     ),
     cte(period, total_amount, r_amount, seqnum) as (
      select period, total_amount, r_amount, seqnum
      from t
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select t.period, t.total_amount, t.total_amount - cte.r_amount, t.seqnum
      from cte join
           t
           on t.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

This question explicitly talks about "recursively" adding values.  If you want to solve this using another mechanism, you might explain the logic in detail and ask if there is a non-recursive CTE solution.